# Using bootstrap-datepicker in Drupal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, datepicker, drupal-modules

I'm trying to add the bootstrap-datepicker plugin to a Drupal custom module based page. My problem is the function below does not give any sort of errors but the datepicker never shows up.

```
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                       jQuery('#datepicker1').datepicker({
                       format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
                      });
                });
```

I have added both bootstrap-datepicker.js and datepicker.css using the info file

```
         stylesheets[all][] = stylesheets/datepicker.css
         scripts[] = js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
         scripts[] = js/filterBlock.js
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add jQuery.js once more to the module info file even though I had enabled the jQuery Update plugin. But now it's working.

```
scripts[] = js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
scripts[] = js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
stylesheets[all][] = stylesheets/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = stylesheets/datepicker.css
```

Is there a better solution? Does any one know why I have to add the jQuery.js once again?
I  have some other issues with bootstrap elements like panel when I add this jQuery like this.If someone can guess what is missing without the jQuery for the bootstrap-datepicker it would be great.

Comment: When you use jquery only once, if you look at your JS console, are you getting errors? . Could the issue be because the bootstrap-datepicker.js is being called before jquery-1.7.1.min.js?

Comment: @julianromera No there are no errors in the console. Even the .datepicker function does not show the datepicker function not present for the object. But the datepicker justo wont work. I'm not sure the order in which the js and css are loaded in drupal but I think jQuery should be loaded initally since almost all other stuff works.

Comment: Found another issue with this. The datepicker is not working only when  I login with a administrator account in drupal. For a normal registered user the datepicker is working fine. Even without the http://idaids.colostate.edu/listIDAids mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiarized with drupal, but recently I have used bootstrap on a Struts2 project. Even though I used Bootstrap, ended up using jQueryUI Datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), which not only works perfectly, but also brings the possibility of adapting it to a (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/TimePicker).

Comment: Yeah Datepicker is really nice which is why I wanted to use it. I have used it in other projects but I'm unable to use it in Drupal..